# Retry all hosts forever Retry Policy?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have some data that *must* be written to Cassandra.  Initially I thought this would be simple by just setting up a RetryPolicy for ReadTimeout, WriteTimeout, Unavailable and RequestError.  However, the only two retry decisions that I see are `tryNextHost` and `retry`.

`retry` appears to try forever, but it tries the same host over and over again.  Even if the node cleanly leaves the cluster and announces its departure (handing off ownership of its range to another node), this retry policy appears to continue to try to send to the same host.

`tryNextHost` solves that problem, but it appears to only try each host once and then gives up (lets the exception bubble up).

I need a retry policy that rotates through hosts (or at least moves hosts when one cleanly leaves the cluster) but I can set to retry forever.  I investigated writing my own RetryDecision but there is no public constructor and even if I got around that, I don't see a way to get around this since its constructor is pretty limited.

How can I retry forever *AND* rotate hosts?

Answer (score 2):

`RetryPolicy` alone will not allow you to do that. The other component involved is [LoadBalancingPolicy](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/load_balancing/), which determines which hosts will be tried (in other words, it generates the sequence over which repeated `tryNextHost` calls would iterate).

So I guess you could write a custom load balancing policy that returns infinite iterators. But frankly that's quite unusual and you should consider the implications of requests potentially looping forever.

Comment: I'll look into `LoadBalancingPolicy` and see what I can come up with.  The service can control its ingest rate and if something fails it is better to stop processing until a human can investigate than to just move on without writing the message.  Also, the retry policy is specifically setup for timouts and unavailable, both of which most often means a problem with the cluster and not a problem with the request itself.

The problem with retrying each host once is if the cluster is unreachable (network split).  I need protection against both hardware failure (node down) and cluster unreachable.

Comment: I have implemented a custom `LoadBalancingPolicy` that returns an infinite iterator that repeatedly calls the `TokenAware` policy iterator (anytime it runs out).  I'll be testing this tomorrow and if it works I'll accept this answer.